# Load image from a .rar folder from assest folder

Tags: android

I have a folder which is compressed. My compressed folder's name is "myfolder.rar".
It contains several images. So i want to load images into a imageview from this .rar folder.
I know how to load images from assets folder in android.

```
 ImageView   mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        try 
        {
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("myfolder.rar/abstinent.jpg");
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            // set image to ImageView
            mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

So i put my "myfolder.rar" folder into assets folder and tried to load images form this folder. But it didn't work.
Is there anyway to load images form a .rar folder in android??

Comment: Better not to use a compressed archive. You can run into memory issues, if you unpack it **in memory**. OR, you have to unpack it **on the storage**, first.

Comment: for this you will have to decompress the rar file to sdcard and use it from there else that won't be possible.

Comment: Why are you packaging a RAR file in the first place? An APK is a ZIP archive and is already compressed.

Comment: "myfolder.rar/abstinent.jpg" You really don't know how archives work, do you? Just unpack and put all the images directly in the assets folder. Like CommonsWare says, the final APK will be archived already

Answer (score 0):

For decompressing .rar files you would like to move with third party library like [junrar](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar)

if you want to use .zip, you may want to check java util Class ZipInputStream,ZipOutputstream and ZIPEntry one example for decompressing using ZipEntry is given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/)